# How to iterate through pandas series with 2 indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a series `my_series` that looks like this:

```
Index           Date      
12345           2019-01-03     14.0
                2019-01-04     65.0
                2019-01-05     81.0
                                
23456           2019-12-14    21.0
                2019-12-15    51.0
                2019-12-16    55.0
```

and I want to go through its values by selecting both indexes, because I need to perform an operation with each value.

Currently what I'm doing is something like this:

```
a_dict = {
    index : my_series[index,date] * 2 for index,date in my_series
}
```

but keep getting this error:

> 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got what I needed, so I'm posting how I solved it in case anyone else is in need.

So basically I was trying to access `for index,date in my_series` ,
the variable `index` included both cols "Index" and "Date". I had to access the 'Index' value alone, so what I had to do was:

```
 a_dict = {
      index[0] : value * 2 for index,value in my_series.items()
}
```

In this case, `index` refers to both "Index" and "Date" in my series. And by looping my_seires.items() I get to access both the indexes and my values of interest. Not sure if its clear what I mean, but I'm new to Python Pandas haha

Answer (score 0):

Use a `groupby` on `level='Index'`:

```
df.groupby(level='Index').apply(function)
```

Or in a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {k: function(g) for k, g in df.groupby(level='Index')}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work as I expected :\ The series in question already comes from some aggregation in a grouped dataframe, but it has 2 indexes. I need to access those float numbers by iterating over both of them.

Comment: @backer can you please provide a reproducible input and the matching expected output?